# Solve system of first order ODEs when values are a matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I have a set of first order ODEs such that

$$ \frac{d \Psi}{ds} = H(s)\Psi$$

H(s) is an 8x8 matrix.

I would like to find $\Psi(b)$ where $b$ is 10, for instance. The initial value for $\Psi(a)$ is a 8x8 identity matrix when $a$ is 5, for instance.

Normally I would solve something like this in Matlab using `ode45` (Runge-Kutta), but I'm not sure how to handle this when $\Psi$ is a matrix instead of a vector.

Is there anything special that needs to be done when $\Psi$ is a matrix instead of a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: Nothing changes. You can interpret your matrix equation as 8 vector equations, i.e. $\Psi=(\Psi_1,\ldots,\Psi_8)$ where $\Psi_1,\ldots,\Psi_8$ are vector valued functions. There is no kind of "interaction" between the 8 equations, i.e. you can solve them independently. I can also imagine (just give it a try) that matlab won't bother wether you have a vector or a matrix as initial value.

Comment: FYI, Matlab's ODE solvers only work with vectors, but yes you can use a matrix initial condition. That matrix will be linearized along it's rows, i.e, `y0 = y0(:);`. The user-written integration function will still need to take in and return vectors.

Comment: I see, thank you for this remark. So you could implement the above problem by replacing the matrix H by a 64x64 block diagonal matrix which contains 8 copies of the original H and then pass the the initial value as a matrix.

Comment: I was understanding horchler a little differently. $\Psi$ would be an array (1x64) passed to the integration function, in the integration function it would be changed to an 8x8 matrix, multiplied by H(s) such that $\frac{d \Psi}{ds} = H(s) \Psi$, then $\frac{d \Psi}{ds}$ is  re-formulated as an array (1x64) and return from the integration function. Will this work?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can either convert the input vector into an 8x8 matrix and then multiply it with the actual H and then convert it back into a vector, or you can do what I have written before. The only difference could be the performance of your programme. To me, your solution sounds faster but I think you have to try it (or you have to know very precisely how matlab works internaly